# Centos 7 + sendmail is sending from wrong hostname

Tags: centos, sendmail, centos7, postfix-mta

I'm stumped: when an email arrives from my server, its from the wrong hostname.

Centos 7

```
$ postconf -n
....
myhostname = myserver.example.com
....
$ hostname --fqdn
myserver.example.com

$ cat /etc/hosts
123.123.123.123 myserver myserver.example.com
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

But when receiving an email sent from this host, the From address is different.domain.com

I do see that there is no /etc/mail directory nor /etc/mail/sendmail.cf or /etc/mail/sendmail.mc files.

Ideas, suggestions?

Dan

Comment: does it come from a domain you control on the same server? some random 3rd party domain or localhost? if you have no `sendmail.cf` are you *certain* your server is using sendmail to process its mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to check your logs! Is it REALLY Postfix sending the mail or is it a leftover sendmail install?

When Postfix is running: The address used in the sender (envelope and header) is governed by the **myorigin** parameter. It defaults to:

myorigin = $myhostname

So, it should be "myserver.example.com"